# WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://192.168.100.10:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket in Flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, websocket

I'm trying to establish a WebSocket connection between my Flutter app and a WebSocket server running at http://192.168.100.10:6001. However, when I run the app, I get the following error in the console:
flutter (10118): WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://192.168.100.10:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket
I've double-checked the server address and it seems to be correct. I've also verified that the server is running and listening on port 6001. What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Here's the code I'm using to create the WebSocket connection:
IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://192.168.100.10:6001', <String, dynamic>{
'transports': ['websocket'],
'autoConnect': false
});

```
socket.connect();
socket.onConnect((_) {
    print('Connection established');
});

/*socket.on('App\\Events\\NewMessageEvent', (data) {
    print('event reached');
    print(data);
});*/

socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('Connection Disconnection'));
socket.onConnectError((err) => print(err));
socket.onError((err) => print(err));
```

I'm ecpecting the message Connection established to be printed in flutter console but i get the error instead , i have tried diffrent ways to establish the connection but all of them failed

Comment: and here is my laravel code of the event i'm triying to listen to in flutter //.................public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('public.newmessage.1');
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'message' => $this->message,
        ];
    }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.